# What is the format of the value of a transaction in the litecoin ledger

Tags: litecoin

Feeling a little silly here, I can decode the entire rest of the data in the blockchain, but the "value" field of a transaction output makes no sense.

```
[0,-14,5,42,1,0,0,0]
```

This decodes to "50.00000000" but I can't see how.

The remainder of the block decodes correctly, so I am fairly sure I'm looking at the right data. It doesnt seem to be in the same format as the bitcoin value (/10^8)

Comment: @NickODell I tried that, if I interpret it as a 64 bit big endian I get `15861034`, as little endian I get `705032704`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction format was never altered in the clone Tenebrix or its clone Litecoin. The bytes you have posted are correct, and do indeed decode to 50 BTC when read out as an unsigned, little endian, 64 bit integer.

```
~> python
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("<q","\x00\xF2\x05\x2A\x01\x00\x00\x00")[0]
5000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using Java's .getInt() rather than .getLong()